# Sql Query returns single row, but not all

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get records with a single SQL query. There are many records in the database but it returns only 1 row.

For example:
it returns record no. 1. If i delete this record then it returns record no. 2. As there are many records. I want it to display all the records.

Here is my Query.

```
SELECT camp.title, camp.status, c.name, b.base_id, count(s.base_id) as subscribers
FROM campaigns as camp
JOIN company as c ON c.id = camp.company_id
JOIN campaign_numbers as b ON b.campaign_id = camp.id
JOIN base_numbers as s ON s.base_id = b.base_id
WHERE camp.campaign_date = '2017-04-07' AND camp.approved = 1
```

What i actually want my query to return all the `campaigns` for `current date` which is `2017-04-07` and `approved` status should be `1` but my query is returning only single row, not all campaigns.

If i do this, it returns all..

```
SELECT title, status
From Campaigns
WHERE campaign_date = '2017-04-07' AND approved = 1
```

But i also want to show company name and also want to count all subscribers too. WHere am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an aggregation function in the `SELECT` with no `GROUP BY`.  In most databases, this would return an error.  In MySQL, this is an aggregation query that always returns one row.

Presumably you want the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY camp.title, camp.status, c.name, b.base_id
```

Comment: Damn I took 2 hours to fix this but unable to do it. You are so quick, It worked.. Thanks so much!

Comment: @7venShots . . . You can set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP BY` mode to prevent this problem in the future.  This is now the default in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Comment: I am trying to use this query in PHP, how will i set this ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ?

Comment: @7venShots . . . You need to do that inside the database or perhaps when you make the connection.

Answer (score 0):

try as below

```
SELECT camp.title, camp.status, c.name, b.base_id, count(s.id) as subscribers
FROM campaigns as camp
 Left JOIN company as c ON c.id = camp.company_id
 Left JOIN campaign_numbers as b ON b.campaign_id = camp.id
 Left JOIN base_numbers as s ON s.base_id = b.base_id
 WHERE camp.campaign_date = '2017-04-07' AND camp.approved = 1
 group by camp.title, camp.status, c.name, b.base_id
```